# Bootstrap data-toggle attribute disables change event - Angular

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my Angular template I have this bit of code:

```
  <div class = "btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <input type="text" class = "form-control" [(ngModel)]="siteFilter[filterType]" placeholder="Refine Search">
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" (change)="changeFilter('1')" autocomplete="off">1
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default active">
        <input type="radio" (change)="changeFilter('2')" autocomplete="off" checked>2
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" (change)="changeFilter('3')" autocomplete="off">3
    </label>
</div>
```

When I use the `data-toggle="buttons"` attribute, my `(change)="changeFilter()` is not even triggered. How do I keep the the `data-toggle` functionality and have the `change` event trigger on a `radio` press?

Comment: You may consider using [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) (Angular 4 + Bootstrap 4). The [NgbRadioGroup](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/buttons/api) could give you the functionality that you are looking for. See [the code examples](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/buttons/examples).

Comment: Yes, in hindsight I should have used `ng-bootstrap` from the beginning, but I'd prefer to not have to convert the whole app now. Is there a way I can use `ng-bootstrap` without affecting the rest of my Bootstrap 3 elements?

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with Bootstrap but I doubt that you can mix Bootstrap 3 (CSS + jQuery) with ng-bootstrap (Bootstrap 4 CSS, without jQuery). Mixing the two might be more complicated than converting to ng-bootstrap and [upgrading to Bootstrap 4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was have a flag variable for each of my inputs:

```
[ngClass]="nameFilterActive ? 'btn btn-default active': 'btn btn-default'
```

Then in my Component I had a function that would change the flags depending on what was pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to to bind the click event on the label (it worked for me):

```
<label class="btn btn-default" (click)="changeFilter('1')">
    <input type="radio" autocomplete="off">1
</label>
```

Comment: I believe I tried that. That normally works, but does it work with the `data-toggle="buttons"`?

Comment: Yes, I've something working with that; however I'm using bootstrap 4.

Comment: this worked for me after several hours of searching. bootstrap 3. thanks